# Why do Magento 2 extension installation instructions tell me to unzip their file to the root and then run command?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, magento-2.1.2

I'm not a developer, and I have learned Magento 2 (my store was installed with Magento 2.1.2 through Softaculous on Cpanel) in the past 3 weeks.  I don't mind learning.  I'm sure there are many others similar to me trying to install and run their own stores with no dedicated web infrastructure and huge budget.  So this is a question that will hopefully help my understanding as well as theirs.

I had to ask for help with installing several extensions in my store.  Some are free and some have been paid for. I followed the directions of these extensions and most tell me to:

1. "Unzip the file my-great-extension.zip into your Magento root folder".  I'm well aware that the root folder of the Magento 2 installation is the folder where your Magento 2 store is installed, the same folder containing the directories "app" and "pup" and "var" and "vendor".
2. The next step is usually a miffing "enable the extension".  Once in a while, they explain the command line code to enable the extension: bin/magento module:enable my-great-extensions-name but usually not.
3. Clear the cache, again not very specific to people that don't know Magento 2.

Usually, this ends up, if I followed the directions to the "T", in an error message at the command line:

"Unknown module(s): 'my great unknown module does not exist because i gave you the wrong installation instructions'"

THEN, I ask for help.  Now after the first time, I figured out that these instructions were either wrong or not applicable to my installation.  The upload was never to the root directory.  I was following instructions, but I was ACTUALLY supposed to the uploaded the unzipped files to the app -> code directory WITHOUT OVERWRITING OTHER FILES IN THERE and mimic the unzipped file structure.

So this is where the problem comes in along with my questions?

1. Firstly, are installation instructions different for every variation of the same Magento release store.  Meaning, are the installation methods different for every Magento 2.1.2 store?  Or IS THERE A STANDARD INSTALLATION PROCEDURE FOR MANUAL INSTALLS OF EXTENSIONS.
2. Are the installation instructions that I'm so often given by documentation for extensions even the CORRECT instructions?  Now not speaking about the free extensions, but it seems to me that this is a good way for extension developers to make a little extra money per installation, which I'm all for, but it should be stated like so, and not swindled. (no offense to the developers, we all love what you folks do and wish we could do it too).
3. Is my Magento installation incorrect?

Sorry for the slight rant, but I'd still like to find the right way to install extensions.  Some come with more then just the "code" folder in it, in those cases, am I supposed to copy over they others as well?  It's almost never that well documented.

*EDIT*  FOR THE DOWNVOTERS...if your an extension maker, it's probably a good idea to be clear about install instructions for your extensions. Just as the person that answered this was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can confirm your extension name in `registration.php` file of **`app/code/MyGreatExtensions/ModuleName`**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
   'MyGreatExtensions_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

and make sure your extension path is something like `app/code/MyGreatExtensions/ModuleName`

[image]

here, `MyGreatExtensions` is your extension namespace and `ModuleName` is your extension module name.

after unzip you have to follow below instruction:

1. Enable your extension

   `php bin/magento module:enable MyGreatExtensions_ModuleName`
2. Setup upgrade

   `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
3. Remove `var/di`, `var/generation` folder

   `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
4. Remove `pub/static` folder [OPTIONAL] may be your extension has overrides some core code(JS, CSS, etc).

   `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
5. Set proper permission for your Magento store

Comment: Chirag, thanks for clearing this up.  THIS answer is the answer that needs to be posted/utilized by all the extension developers EXCEPT you said "after unzip you have to follow below instruction:"  enabling any extension after simply unzipping in the root directory.  I think that's where my problem started, as with many others.  THE VERY FIRST STEP is wrong.  Or, am I wrong?  Can I just unzip the file in the root directory and expect Magento to take the folder and place it in the right directory before I run the enable command?

Comment: you have to unzip your extension inside `app/` folder.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up.  So example: i have a zipfile.  I upload it into app folder.  When I run unzip, it opens up and a folder called "ExtensionName" is created.  From there I can run the enable command?

Comment: goto that 'ExtensionName'  and open `registration.php` file in that `ExtensionName_ModuleName` and check if its not available then you have to create `ModuleName` folder inside 'ExtensionName' and move all code from `ExtensionName` to 'ModuleName', then you can follow my steps.

Comment: From there I can run the enable command?  Or do I need to move contents of that folder (i.e. an "app" folder located inside the newly created "ExtensionName" folder) to its respective place?  The reason I'm asking if because its a confusing process that most extension makers don't address in install instructions.  For instance, I make an extension, then I put it in a folder called "ExtensionName"  then zip that folder.  That is much different then zipping all the cintents of that folder, and when it is unzipped, it will be different as well.

Comment: Unzipping file.zip in "app" directory (resulting in a directory called "ExtensionName" with contents of an extension, versus unzipping file.zip resulting in a number of different directories (ie. model, view) into "app" directory is what got me stuck AFTER I was told to "upload and unzip".  Sorry to sound like a pest, I hope these answers help someone, cause I spent literally about 300 hours learning Magento along with this, and it seems like the "experts" don't even give the right instructions.

Comment: Chirag...your directions are just whats needed.  Can you post something with those directions so the extension makers, especially the paid ones, can follow protocol.  Feels like they don't post that clear instructions so you HAVE to buy the installation service, which should result in 0 stars from the people paying for the extension.

Comment: Sory about the extra comments.  Post wouldn't submit because of too many characters.  But again,  thank you for clearing this up,  this should be posted everywhere.

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Chirag can the var/di and var/generation directories be deleted altogether?  Or just the contents of each directory?  I have seen people say both.

Comment: yes, you have to delete both recursively .

Comment: Does it work if we move that extension into root folder? Not tried but have a doubt. does it work?

Comment: No, it will not directly work, if you want then you have to add that root path, in vendor/composer/ files. like autoload_files.php, installed.json etc